# Who were Varasikha and Abhyavartin Cayamana?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, indra

In Rig Veda (RV.6.27.4 & 5) it is described that Indra killed people of Varasikha and drove away VRcis in the aid of Abhyavartin Cayamana. [Ralph T.H Griffith's translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06027.htm) follows :-

> 4 This one great power of thine our eyes have witnessed, wherewith thou slewest Varasikha's children,
>   When by the force of thy descending thunder, at the mere sound, their boldest was demolished.
>
> 5 **In aid of Abhyavartin Cayamana, Indra destroyed the seed of Varasikha**.
>   At Hariyupiya he smote the vanguard of the Vrcivans, and the rear fled frighted

Is there any scripture elaborating this story? Who were Varasikha and Abhyavartin Cayamana?